# Maven dependency-convergence report in a multi-module project

Tags: maven, maven-site-plugin

I'm trying to use the [dependency-convergence report](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-project-info-reports-plugin/dependency-convergence-mojo.html) of the maven-project-info-reports plugin in a multi-module project that looks like:

```
test-project-parent
   + test-lib-a
   + test-lib-b
```

If I run `site:site` on the `test-lib-a` pom I get the report I expect showing dependency convergence for that project.

[image]

If I run `site:site` on the parent pom, a dependency convergence report is generated for each project but all three reports are the same and they include information about the whole reactor build instead of just each particular project.

[image]

How can I make the report generated for each module show only the information about that module and not the whole reactor build?

**EDIT:** This is my parent pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

   <groupId>org.example</groupId>
   <artifactId>site-test-parent</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <packaging>pom</packaging>
   <name>Maven Site Test</name>

   <modules>
      <module>test-lib-a</module>
      <module>test-lib-b</module>
   </modules>

   <reporting>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <reportSets>
               <reportSet>
                  <reports>
                     <report>dependency-convergence</report>
                  </reports>
               </reportSet>
            </reportSets>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </reporting>

</project>
```

This is the test-lib-a pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

   <parent>
      <groupId>org.example</groupId>
      <artifactId>site-test-parent</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   </parent>

   <artifactId>test-lib-a</artifactId>

   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
         <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
         <version>2.4</version>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
</project>
```

The second screenshot is what gets generated in `site-test/test-lib-a/target/site/dependency-convergence.html` when I run `site:site` on the parent.

Comment: Could you share your report plugin configuration and which pom have you declared the same in?

Comment: Okay, added. They're very simple since this is just a test project so I can explore configuring various reports before applying them to my real project.

Answer (score 0):

So just to add two things from an attempt I made after with a similar configuration on one of my projects -

```
<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <reportSets>
                <reportSet>
                    <reports>
                        <report>dependency-convergence</report>
                    </reports>
                </reportSet>
            </reportSets>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

1. > How can I make the report generated for each module show only the
   >   information about that module and not the whole reactor build?

The only way I could figure out to generate different reports for `dependency-convergence` on different modules was to execute `mvn:site` on each module individually.

2. From the [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-project-info-reports-plugin/dependency-convergence-mojo.html) as shared by you as well. This doesn't seem to justify the point *`as an aggregator plugin.`*, since I would expect the reports to be generated module(child module) specific when I run `mvn:site` on the parent level.

Though I doubt the specific words *(reactor) builds* from the line

> project-info-reports:dependency-convergence is used to generate the
>   Project Dependency Convergence report for (reactor) builds.

might mean that it generates the convergence report for a specific build.

Probably raising/reporting this to the mailing list may help further over this. Alias for which I hope is correctly put ***dev@maven.apache.org***.